# How to take backup of Biztalk dll from GAC

Tags: c#, .net, dll, biztalk, gac

I have a biz talk dll(Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.dll) available in GAC which i can see from the path `C:\WINDOWS\assembly (file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly)`. I want to take backup of this dll.

I read few article on stack overflow and other sites, they suggested dll is available under `C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM (file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM)`. But in my case I don't have any `Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM` folder under `GAC_MSIL`.

Whereas the folder exists for other dlls. Please help how can I manage to take backup of the dll.

Comment: Can you please let us know what version of BizTalk you use?

Comment: Why not simply backup the dll in its original location and add to GAC if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not responding to the comment I made, I'm going to assume you are using `Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010`.

I did a quick search on the C: drive using the good old command '`dir`' on a BizTalk machine, and this gave me pointers to two locations:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Developer Tools\Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.dll"

and

"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM\3.0.1.0__31bf3856ad364e35"

Note that you probably will not be able to access the second location using a Windows Explorer. Using the command prompt to access it, works just fine.

[image: Image to access the GAC using command line.]

If you want to copy it from the GAC on the location, just use the copy command to copy it to your desired location.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others you haven't specified your BizTalk version (or more importantly, your Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.dll framework version) so I will make some assumptions. You are looking in the pre .NET4 GAC (c:\windows\assembly), have a look in the post .NET4 GAC (c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly) it might be in there.

If not, you can extract assemblies from the .NET2 GAC by running the following cmds:

```
cd C:\Windows\assembly
attrib desktop.ini -s -h –r
ren desktop.ini desktop.ini.bak
```

You will notice that if you now browse to c:\windows\assembly that it's just a normal file structure, where you can copy files out as you wish. To put is back:

```
ren desktop.ini.bak desktop.ini
```

I believe that this will answer your question however, depending on your BizTalk version and how you have installed the assemblies, if you installed by running a BizTalk MSI then you should have an install path (default %ProgramFiles%\Generated By BizTalk) which will contain all of the assemblies that you are after

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOS command [Copy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb490886.aspx) at command prompt to copy the Biz Talk DLL.

Please route to the Biz Talk DLL folder using command prompt.

GAC folder path is - c:\Windows\Assembly\GAC\

Answer (score 0):

they are located at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

If you want to view the folder structure of the GAC in Windows Explorer, you can do this by using the registry: Launch regedit. Navigate to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion. Add a DWORD called DisableCacheViewer and set the value to 1